# Whence does the habit comes from of defining navigation menus as ul / li ? Is it still relevant?

Tags: html

I've almost never seen it done any other way, however it would seem more logical to use a `<nav>` along with some `<button>`

One benefit is that the label of a button is not selectable, which makes for a cleaner navigation. Code-wise, `<nav>` and `<button>` make sense immediately, whereas it requires a bit of interpretation to determine that a particular `<ul>` has a particular role.

I suppose that it's an old habit predating HTML5 or even style sheets, but I don't see any reason to carry it on. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Why `<button>`s? Navigation items usually are links to other documents, so you want to use `<a>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

A typical navigation menu is made up of links (so `<a>` fits better than `<button>` which would submit a form), which are in a list which isn't designed to be followed in sequence (so `<ul>` is appropriate).

`<nav>` is a new feature in HTML 5, which can *supplement* this. The example use given on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav) shows a `<nav>` containing a `<ul>`.